# Efficient tensor contraction with Python

Tags: python, complexity-theory, tensor

I have a piece of code with a bottleneck calculation involving tensor contractions. Lets say I want to calculate a tensor A_{i,j,k,l}( X ) whose non-zero entries for a single x\in X are N ~ 10^5, and X represents a grid with M total points, with M~1000 approximately. For a single element of the tensor A, the rhs of the equation looks something like:

A_{ijkl}(M) = Sum_{m,n,p,q} S_{i,j, m,n }(M) B_{m,n,p,q}(M) T_{ p,q, k,l }(M)

In addition, the middle tensor B_{m,n,p,q}(M) is obtained by numerical convolution of arrays so that:

B_{m,n,p,q}(M) = ( L_{m,n} * F_{p,q} )(M)

where "*" is the convolution operator, and all tensors have appoximately the same number of elements as A. My problem has to do with efficiency of the sums; to compute a single rhs of A, it takes very long times given the complexity of the problem. I have a "keys" system, where each tensor element is accessed by its unique key combination ( ( p,q,k,l ) for T for example ) taken from a dictionary. Then the dictionary for that specific key gives the Numpy array associated to that key to perform an operation, and all operations (convolutions, multiplications...) are done using Numpy. I have seen that the most time consuming part is actually due to the nested loop (I loop over all keys (i,j,k,l) of the A tensor, and for each key, a rhs like the one above needs to be computed). Is there any efficient way to do this? Consider that:

1) Using simple numpy arrays of 4 +1 D results in high memory usage, since all tensors are of type complex
2 ) I have tried several approaches: Numba is quite limited when working with dictionaries, and some important Numpy features that I need are not currently supported. For instance, the numpy.convolve() only takes the first 2 arguments, but does not take the "mode" argument which reduces considerably the needed convolution interval in this case, I dont need the "full" output of the convolution

3) My most recent approach is trying to implement everything using Cython for this part... But this is quite time consuming as well as more error prone given the logic of the code.

Any ideas on how to deal with such complexity using Python?

Thanks!

Comment: The first step would be to write an example code using https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html with optimize="optimal". Also add the typical size of the tensor (this is also important for optimizing the problem) Also array ordering and contigous memory access is very important.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your question a bit more precise, which also includes a working code example which you have already tried. It is for example unclear, why you use dictionarys in this tensor contractions. Dictionary lookups looks to be a weard thing for this calculation, but maybe I didn't get the point what you really want to do.

Tensor contraction actually is very easy to implement in Python (Numpy), there are methods to find the best way to contract the tensors and they are really easy to use (np.einsum).

**Creating some data (this should be part of the question)**

```
import numpy as np
import time

i=20
j=20
k=20
l=20

m=20
n=20
p=20
q=20

#I don't know what complex 2 means, I assume it is complex128 (real and imaginary part are in float64)

#size of all arrays is 1.6e5
Sum_=np.random.rand(m,n,p,q).astype(np.complex128)
S_=np.random.rand(i,j,m,n).astype(np.complex128)
B_=np.random.rand(m,n,p,q).astype(np.complex128)
T_=np.random.rand(p,q,k,l).astype(np.complex128)
```

**The naive way**

This code is basically the same as writing it in loops using Cython or Numba without calling BLAS routines (ZGEMM) or optimizing the contraction order -> 8 nested loops to do the job.

```
t1=time.time()
A=np.einsum("mnpq,ijmn,mnpq,pqkl",Sum_,S_,B_,T_)
print(time.time()-t1)
```

This results in a very slow runtime of about 330 seconds.

**How to increase the speed by a factor of 7700**

```
%timeit A=np.einsum("mnpq,ijmn,mnpq,pqkl",Sum_,S_,B_,T_,optimize="optimal")
#42.9 ms ± 2.71 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**Why is this so much faster?**

Lets have a look at the contraction path and the internals.

```
path=np.einsum_path("mnpq,ijmn,mnpq,pqkl",Sum_,S_,B_,T_,optimize="optimal")
print(path[1])

    #  Complete contraction:  mnpq,ijmn,mnpq,pqkl->ijkl
#         Naive scaling:  8
#     Optimized scaling:  6
#      Naive FLOP count:  1.024e+11
#  Optimized FLOP count:  2.562e+08
#   Theoretical speedup:  399.750
#  Largest intermediate:  1.600e+05 elements
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#scaling                  current                                remaining
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   4             mnpq,mnpq->mnpq                     ijmn,pqkl,mnpq->ijkl
#   6             mnpq,ijmn->ijpq                          pqkl,ijpq->ijkl
#   6             ijpq,pqkl->ijkl                               ijkl->ijkl
```

and

```
path=np.einsum_path("mnpq,ijmn,mnpq,pqkl",Sum_,S_,B_,T_,optimize="optimal",einsum_call=True)
print(path[1])

#[((2, 0), set(), 'mnpq,mnpq->mnpq', ['ijmn', 'pqkl', 'mnpq'], False), ((2, 0), {'n', 'm'}, 'mnpq,ijmn->ijpq', ['pqkl', 'ijpq'], True), ((1, 0), {'p', 'q'}, 'ijpq,pqkl->ijkl', ['ijkl'], True)]
```

Doing the contraction in multiple well choosen steps reduces the required flops by a factor of 400. But thats not the only thing what einsum does here. Just have a look at `'mnpq,ijmn->ijpq', ['pqkl', 'ijpq'], True), ((1, 0)` the True stands for a BLAS contraction -> tensordot call -> (matrix matix multiplication).

Internally this looks basically as follows:

```
#consider X as a 4th order tensor {mnpq}
#consider Y as a 4th order tensor {ijmn}

X_=X.reshape(m*n,p*q)       #-> just another view on the data (2D), costs almost nothing (no copy, just a view)
Y_=Y.reshape(i*j,m*n)       #-> just another view on the data (2D), costs almost nothing (no copy, just a view)
res=np.dot(Y_,X_)           #-> dot is just a wrapper for highly optimized BLAS functions, in case of complex128 ZGEMM
output=res.reshape(i,j,p,q) #-> just another view on the data (4D), costs almost nothing (no copy, just a view)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response. Unfortunately, the arrays are 5D, which means that in your concrete example, an extra dimension is missing, for which I am experiencing memory problems. This extra dimension contains a total of ~1000 points, so rapidly the tensor's size becomes unmanageable in memory. The reason to do the outer loop is twofold: first, because of the memory issues I run into, and second, because the considered tensors are "sparse", which means I only account for non-zero entries. I have read that Scipy offers sparse matrices support for 2D but what about d>2D ?

Comment: In most cases the first part of optimization is to avoid larger temporary arrays. It is also unclear how sparse the data actually is. This is the case for every programming language (C,Fortran,...). You never win the game with an alogorithm which has a suboptimal complexity if the problem is large enough. There is also a reason why large amount circuits on a processor is spent on caching data. To make things short, provide a simple, but relevant example.You can operate on almost a TB of data in a second if it is small enough to fit in lower level cache or even  processor-registers.