# Fastest Way to Find the Dot Product of a Large Matrix of Vectors

Tags: python, numpy, tensordot

I am looking for suggestions on the most efficient way to solve the following problem:

I have two arrays called A and B. They are both of shape NxNx3. They represent two 2D matrix of positions, where each position is a vector of x, y, and z coordinates.

I want to create a new array, called C, of shape NxN, where C[i, j] is the dot product of the vectors A[i, j] and B[i, j].

Here are the solutions I've come up with so far. The first uses the numpy's einsum function ([which is beautifully described here](https://ajcr.net/Basic-guide-to-einsum/)). The second uses numpy's broadcasting rules along with its sum function.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.random.randint(0, 10, (100, 100, 3))
>>> B = np.random.randint(0, 10, (100, 100, 3))
>>> C = np.einsum("ijk,ijk->ij", A, B)
>>> D = np.sum(A * B, axis=2)
>>> np.allclose(C, D)
True
```

Is there a faster way? I've heard murmurs that numpy's tensordot function can be blazing fast but I've always struggled to understand it. What about using numpy's dot, or inner functions?

For some context, the A and B arrays will typically have between 100 and 1000 elements.

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: Einsum with optimize=True/"greedy"/"optimize" is in some cases just a wrapper for tensordot. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62415935/4045774 But this problem this isn't possible (one BLAS-call to do all the calculation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit of reshaping, we can use `matmul`.  The idea is to treat the first 2 dimensions as the 'batch' dimensions, and to the `dot` on the last:

```
In [278]: E = A[...,None,:]@B[...,:,None]                                       
In [279]: E.shape                                                               
Out[279]: (100, 100, 1, 1)
In [280]: E = np.squeeze(A[...,None,:]@B[...,:,None])                           
In [281]: np.allclose(C,E)                                                      
Out[281]: True
In [282]: timeit E = np.squeeze(A[...,None,:]@B[...,:,None])                    
130 µs ± 2.01 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [283]: timeit C = np.einsum("ijk,ijk->ij", A, B)                             
90.2 µs ± 1.53 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comparative timings can be a bit tricky.  In the current versions, `einsum` can take different routes depending on the dimensions.  In some cases it appears to delegate the task to `matmul` (or at least the same underlying BLAS-like code).  While it's nice that `einsum` is faster in this test, I wouldn't generalize that.

`tensordot` just reshapes (and if needed transposes) the arrays so it can apply the ordinary 2d `np.dot`.  Actually it doesn't work here because you are treating the first 2 axes as a 'batch', where as it does an `outer product` on them.

Comment: What about `np.inner`?

Comment: Did you try it?  The result is a (100,100,100,100).  The docs say it's the same as `tensordot` on the last axes.  That's inner on the last axis, but outer on the first two.  You don't want that.  You want a 'batch' behavior on the first two, which is what `matmul` provides.